# Rails : post-processing a rendered view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some Rails application generates a view with some information displayed about a resource.

I'd like to suppress some of the information through a plugin, without altering nor overriding the view. (A possible way is to rewrite the view in the plugin but this may interfere with other plugins, and I don't want that.)

Is there a way to modify the controller instead, so that the generated view is post-processed before being sent to the client?

Can this be achieved with `after_filter` ? I try to find an example of `after_filter` usage, but the documentation seems low and I can't find a good example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`render_to_string`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string) instead of `render` to first render the view to a string.