# centralized post-process of all rendered views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a post render step to all rendered views from a centralized point in a rails app with the goal to remove certain keywords from all server responses.

So far I have found this [Rails : post-processing a rendered view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547905/rails-post-processing-a-rendered-view) that shows how to render view as a string. - Nice.

Since I have a base controller I was thinking of adding some sort of before_render filter that would pass me the rendered_string to allow me to replace it and then render it from there. Here I got stuck and am now thinking whether this is at all possible. Some high-level code looks like this:

```
class BaseClass
  before_render :replace_some_key_words 

  def replace_some_key_words(rendered_string)
    render rendered_string.sub! 'foo', 'bar'
  end
```

(I found an implementation of before_render at http://qiita.com/cryeo/items/d116192fb355411f9008 but I am simply just not enought into rails to understand if what I want is possible from this)

Thankful for all suggestions.

Comment: Way back (rails 1.x) you could do this with an after_filter - don't know if it still works (we use to render xml from the rails app and use the after filter to rewrite the response as html with xslt)

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried some Rack Middleware? Questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080065/in-rails-can-i-access-response-body-in-a-action-before-it-returns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823170/hello-world-rack-middleware-with-rails-3-how-to-process-body-of-all-requests), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564883/alter-response-body-in-rack-middleware) seem to have answers that use this approach. With Rails 4.5, I found the `body` of the `Rack::Response` to be immutable, so this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564883/alter-response-body-in-rack-middleware) proved particularly useful. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
module AfterRender
  require 'rack'
  CONTENT_LENGTH = 'Content-Length'

  class SanitizeResponse
    def initialize(app)
      @app=app
    end

    def call(env)
      status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
      if response.present? and response.respond_to? :body
        new_response_body = sanitize_body(response.body)
        headers[CONTENT_LENGTH] = new_response_body.length.to_s if headers[CONTENT_LENGTH].present?
        new_response = Rack::Response.new([new_response_body], status, headers)
        return [status, headers, new_response]
      end
      return [status, headers, response]
    end

    def sanitizeBody(body)
      to_ret = body.dup
      to_ret.gsub!('string_to_be_replaced', 'replacement_string')
      to_ret
    end
  end
end
```

I check that `response.body` is defined to ensure no funkiness occurs while sending over files for my angular app (they use `Sprockets::Asset` instead of `Rack::Response`). I don't want to be sanitizing those files, anyway. We also only reset the `headers['Content-Length']` if it was already defined, which is not likely the case if `Transfer-Encoding` is chunked. `new_response` could simply be an array (e.g. `[new_response_body]`), but I find it safer to send `response` out the same way it came in, as a `Rack::Response`. This [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/file/SPEC#The_Body) is helpful to understand how the return of `call` must be shaped (i.e. as an array).

To ensure this middleware is actually used, I placed it in a  new file, found at `app/middleware/after_render.rb`. In my `config/application.rb`, I added `require_relative '../app/middleware/after_render.rb'` at the top and `config.middleware.use AfterRender::SanitizeResponse` inside the `Application` class. It looks something like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require_relative '../app/middleware/after_render.rb'

require 'rails/all'

module MyModule
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app"
    config.middleware.use AfterRender::SanitizeResponse
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!